# Want to create for() consisting of Strings

Tags: android

I want to insert a for statement that increments and displays Strings on a TextView when the user clicks the Next button. But when i press the button it displays "3". Can anyone point out where im going wrong. Thanx

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.one:
         break;
        case R.id.Next:
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Test", "Test1", "Test3", "Test4"};
            for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            String s = (String)items[i];
            info.setText(s);

    }

    break;

}

}
```

Comment: So ... what's the "problem"? (I would guess you set the *same* `info` element's text `items.length` times, which is likely not what is desired.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop loops until the last value each time you click the `Button`. If you just want to show the next string:

```
// field 
int value = 0;

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.one:
         break;
        case R.id.Next:
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Test", "Test1", "Test3", "Test4"};            
            if (value < items.length) {
               String s = (String)items[value];
               info.setText(s);
               value++;   
            } 
    }

    break;

}

}
```

Comment: for some strange reason when i press the button it prints out "Test" now but it doesnt print out "Test1" when i press it again. It seems  like its not incrementing correctly

Comment: @Hashey100 Don't put the `int value = 0;` in the method `onClick`, make it a field in your class.

Comment: I just tried it and now it prints "Test4" and just compiles and error if i press it again - wierd =/

Comment: @Hashey100 It's an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  String s = (String)items[value % items.length];
```

to avoid an IndexOutOfBoundsException.